# Where to find Nunit xml parser

Tags: nunit

I have a nunit3 result file, I need to parse and see if the format is right. I tried with nunit-console, does not have an parser option. How can i do the parse?

Comment: You have to either find a system that already has a parser written, or you have to write your own XML parser. ReportUnit can give you helpful HTML pie charts of test results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either use a tool that can parse it or write your own.

A web search for a "NUnit Results Viewer" should give you some choices for existing tools.

You can see the format spec here:
https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Test-Result-XML-Format